# How to make API calls to S3 REST API?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a React web app that needs to make an API call to my S3 bucket given my AWS Access Id and Secret Key. However, I keep getting an error.

This is `state/app.js` where the actions and reducer reside:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
  lrc: '',
};

const config = () => (
  {
    headers: {
      AccessKey: `${process.env.S3_KEY_ID}`,
      SecretKey: `${process.env.S3_SECRET}`,
    },
  }
);

const GET_LRC = 'GET_LRC';
export const getLrc = (url) => (dispatch) => {
  axios.get(url, config())
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_LRC,
        payload: parseLrc(res.data),
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.response.data));
};
...
```

And here is my error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<S3_BUCKET_NAME>/<file>' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' he
```

I have tried setting the CORS policy on my bucket to allow all CORS origins, but it hasn't fixed it. In addition, I'm also unsure whether my authorization header is correct. I think I need to create a signature (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html), but I'm stuck there as well.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [aws-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js) ? It takes care of setting headers etc and provides nice abstractions!

Comment: Would it be a good idea to use aws-sdk-js (or since I'm using React, aws-amplify) or to simply use a package like [aws-signature-v4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-signature-v4) to generate the authorization header?